# ion-radio uncheck on ng-click does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to build my application, i have need where i need to uncheck `ion-radio` button when i click `input` tag, i tried to do so in this [ionic play link](http://play.ionic.io/app/8f1bd4677028), but was not successful

**HTML**

```
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <div class="input-label">
        <i class="ion ion-search"></i>
      </div>
      <input ng-click="uncheck($event)" type="text" ng-model="foodfilter" class="">
    </label>
    <ion-radio ng-model="filter.typefilter" ng-value="'A'">Choose A</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio ng-model="filter.typefilter" ng-value="'B'">Choose B</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio ng-model="filter.typefilter" ng-value="'C'">Choose C</ion-radio>
  </ion-content>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.uncheck = function (event) {
 if ($scope.filter.typefilter == event.target.value) $scope.filter.typefilter = false
}
```

[ionic play link](http://play.ionic.io/app/8f1bd4677028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use ng-click on your input tag.

```
<input ng-click="uncheck($event)" type="text" ng-model="foodfilter" class="">
```

The value of filter.typeFilter is a string so you will want to use value instead of ng-value

```
<ion-radio ng-model="filter.typeFilter" value="A">Choose A</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="filter.typeFilter" value="B">Choose B</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="filter.typeFilter" value="C">Choose C</ion-radio>
```

Also, in order to clear the radio boxes you want to set the value of the ng-model to be the empty string.

```
$scope.filter = {
    typeFilter: ""
}

$scope.uncheck = function (event) {
    $scope.filter.typeFilter = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you exactly how i wanted.

Comment: Working [Ionic Play Link](http://play.ionic.io/app/8f1bd4677028) with your inputs.